# Does Django automatically update child records when the master foreign key is updated?

Tags: django, foreign-keys, cascade

Does Django automatically update child records when the master foreign key is updated? Can it be disabled.

I can see an on.delete function but not an on.update function in the Django docs.

/vfclistsGUY

Comment: what part of the child record to you see requiring updating in this case? could you give a more concrete example (point is, i'm not sure the children need updating at all)

Comment: @second Even if the master record is not directly linked to child records a form, I still need child records to be updated if the master key changes. From the answers received below it appears Django does not support that

Comment: Why would the master key change? That should never happen.

Comment: if your master (primary) key is changing, you have probably chosen the wrong field to use as key. consider a surrogate key, e.g. the autofield django adds by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django doesn't touch the children at all unless you tell it to. Even in the case of DELETE CASCADE, that's an enforcement on the database level, not in Django.

If you are using inline formsets for the children along with the main object's form (or using inlines in the admin... same thing), then Django will update the children as well *if* there's any changes to them. Otherwise, no, Django does nothing.

If you need to update the children on save, you should override your model's `save` method to do whatever needs to be done to the children, or use a `post_save` signal.

Comment: This is correct, except that the delete cascade *is* performed by Django, at the Python level, regardless of the database constraints.